# Nested layout using bootstrap causes misalignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a nested layout using bootstrap 3. I followed the [the tutorial](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) (see the part regarding nesting). The layout basically only contains rows consisting of single columns, however I still need the nesting for technical reasons. My current version is [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aqn5x3t/2/).

In a nutshell, I use alternating row / column divs to achieve the nesting:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Content row 1 (misaligned)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the inner content is misaligned with respect to the surrounding one. I suspect that this is because rows have a negative margin. Is there a way to fix or circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.col` definition for `bootstrap 3`.

[`TWBS-3#css#grid`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) syntax is: `.col-${screen}-${span}` where:

1. `screen = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg']`
2. `span = [1-12]`

So, assuming you want to work with extra small screens your html should look like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          Content row 1 (misaligned)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

here is the official example using `screen = xs`

```css
.txt {
  background: cyan;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 3px 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row { margin-bottom: 50px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-1"><div class="txt">1</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8"><div class="txt">.col-xs-8</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="txt">.col-xs-4</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="txt">.col-xs-4</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="txt">.col-xs-4</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="txt">.col-xs-4</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="txt">.col-xs-6</div></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="txt">.col-xs-6</div></div>
</div>

</section>
```

Comment: I can't see any `.coll` in OP's code, is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

there is no class called ".col1" in bootstrap. you need to give proper column class to get rid if the row margin. try to use the blow code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 "> Content row 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"> Content row 2 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"> Content row 3 </div>
</div>
```